# Determining the number of zeros of a function

Tags: polynomials, roots

The question is:-
**The graph of $y = f(x)$ is given below. How many zeroes are there of $f(x)$?**

[image]

The answer is given **One**.
But as far as I know, if the graph of a function crosses the x-axis, it indicates a zero with an odd number of multiplicity, so the number of zeros can be any odd natural number.
How we can say that the number of zeros is exactly one?
Please help.

Comment: You're not being asked to count multiplicity.

Comment: If this were a multiple zero, then the derivative at $0$ would be $0$, which it is not, by inspection.

Comment: @SeanRoberson: Agreed.

Comment: Because the zero occurs and *one* point.  $x=0$. It wouldn't matter if it has multiplicity.  $x=0$ is only one point and it is the only point where $f(x)=0$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr True but that's irrelevant.  The function $f(x) = x^2$ has one multiple zero and $x=0$.  That is the only zero. the number of zeros that $f(x) = x^2$ has is one.  It is a double zero but it is only zero.

Comment: @fleablood I agree that it's irrelevant to final goal of the problem.  That's one reason that it's a comment and not an answer.  It does, however, address a different confusion that the OP has about the structure of multiple roots.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing the term "number".

The question is asking for **how many zeroes (roots) there are**, not the number of multiplicity. All this requires you to do is count how many times $f(x)=0$.

It looks in the picture like there is one such zero (at the origin), so that is why the answer given is **one**. Compare that to this picture:

[image]

In that picture, there are **three** zeroes.